# How to add an array (customisable) to a symfony2 form (with sonata Admin)?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a simple form with Sonata admin.

I would like the user could add a list of integers (as many as he wants). And after it would be store as an array in my object:

[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]

There any way of doing it without creating another class to instantiate the integers?

**UPDATE:**

The only way I know how to something close is using choice like:

```
 ->add('type', 'choice', [
                "required"           => true,
                "expanded"           => true,
                "multiple"           => false,
                "choices"            => Campanha::getTypes(),
            ])
```

But with that I have a limited number of choices, I would like that it would be free to the user to add the quantity of numbers and the values he wants

Comment: Please show us the code where you've already tried solving this. Where exactly are you blocked?

Comment: @markusthoemmes : updated. I am trying to make a multiple free champ to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into `sonata_type_native_collection`:

From [the Sonata Admin Docs](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-native-collection-previously-collection):

> This bundle handle the native Symfony collection form type by adding:
>
> - an add button if you set the allow_add option to true.
> - a delete button if you set the allow_delete option to true.

And the [Symfony collection form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html):

> This field type is used to render a "collection" of some field or form. In the easiest sense, it could be an array of TextType fields that populate an array emails values.

So, for your case, maybe something like:

```
->add('type', 'sonata_type_native_collection', [
    'required' => true,
    'entry_type' => 'number',
    'options' => [
        // Any options you'd like the integer fields to have.
    ]
])
```

(This doesn't speak at all to the change's you'll need to make to the underlying model, of course.)

**Edit**: Changed the `'entry_options'` array key to `'options'`, as per @Matheus Oliveira's comment.

Comment: It works fine, thanks @CameronHurd

But when I tried to use 'entry_options' (to hide some labels) it doesn't like it very much. it says it doesn't have this field.

I used 'options' => array('label' => false) instead

Comment: Ah, glad you were able to bend it to your will. ;) I'll amend my answer to use the 'options' key instead.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to accomplish this is a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). Look at an example:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class ArrayToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($array)
    {
        if (null === $array) {
            $array = array();
        }

        if (!is_array($array)) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected an array.');
        }

        return implode(',', $array);
    }

    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        if (null === $string || '' === $string) {
            return array();
        }

        if (!is_string($string)) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected a string.');
        }

        return explode(',', $string);
    }
}
```

Later, use it where there is an array field. For greater reusability let's [create a custom field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) which extends of [`TextType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html):

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\ArrayToStringTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ArrayTextType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new ArrayToStringTransformer());
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

That's it! Now you can manage your array fields safely by using your `ArrayTextType`:

```
// in any controller context

public function fooAction() 
{
    $data = array(
        'tags' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    );

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
        ->add('tags', ArrayTextType::class)
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Also we can use any Doctrine `array` mapped field (i.e. `@ORM\Column(name="tags", type="array")`).

Output result:

[image: TagsTextTypeInput]

---

For better data entry I recommend using with this the [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) jQuery plugin. See examples [here](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

[image: BootstrapTagsInput]

Comment: It seems very logical but the other answer fits me much more practically and simply