# simple_array handling with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

My entity has a property from type `simple_array`, storing a list of strings which are generated by the user (so `choice` does not apply).

The relevant part from the entity:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array")
 */
private $tags;
```

I would like to use the SonataAdminBundle to show, create and edit the entity with the tags present:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('tags', 'collection');
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('tags', 'array');
}
```

The list works, but shows `[0 => Tag1, 1 => Tag2]` where I'd rather show `Tag1, Tag2`. The create and edit does not work at all, showing nothing where the input field for the tags should be.

To be clear: Tags are not a related entity, they are simply an array of strings!

Comment: Maybe this answer can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046848/how-to-add-an-array-customisable-to-a-symfony2-form-with-sonata-admin/40052463#40052463 without the data transformer

Comment: Thanks Yonel. The suggested solution works for the add/edit part, but I'm still puzzled by the view part. Any help there is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For add/edit your tags I recommend this general solution [How to add an array (customisable) to a symfony2 form (with sonata Admin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046848/how-to-add-an-array-customisable-to-a-symfony2-form-with-sonata-admin/40052463#40052463)

---

For customization of array values (by defaults) in list mode as you need, just overwrites the [`list_array.html.twig`](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/Resources/views/CRUD/list_array.html.twig) template from SonataAdminBundle, to something like this:

```
{% extends admin.getTemplate('base_list_field') %}

{% block field %}
    {{ value|join(', ') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did 10 minutes ago. I ended up creating my own template for this kind of array list and not overwritting the default one, though!